# Roblox script - random trap activation

Tags: random, local, roblox, activation

I am doing a map and part of it player will have to decide which of let say 3 steps to step on. 1 is OK and will let them pass and others will kill them.

What I am trying to do is to make random activation to ensure each game start with different step being the safe one.

I tried._G to randomly chose number 1-3 and depending on the number step 1,2 or 3 would be the safe one and the other one would be activated kill script. But this never worked.

There is option to clone map and alter manually steps and just random map at start but this seems counterproductive.

Is there a way to make function choose random number at start of the game (random seed) and depending on the number picked in main script (in workplace or other place?) other local scripts can read this number and decide if part is a killing trap or just a brick?

This would allow me to use one number chosen to determine possible other parts of the game. So the player don't get to remember safe way to pass each time they enter the game.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit (old answer below):**

So you just want to generate a random number between 1 and 3 every time the server starts, ensuring that it is actually random (and not the same every time). Previously you'd use math.random() with a math.randomseed() for this, but late 2017 the Random class was introduced.
Two useful links:

- [Announcement of the Random feature](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/a-random-feature/64517)
- [Wiki-article for Random](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/datatype/Random)

In short, here's how you generate a random integer with Random:

```lua
local rng = Random.new(tick()) -- tick() is here used as the seed
local SafeDoor = rng:NextInteger(1, 3) -- will give you a number between (and including) 1 and 3
```

How you choose to tell the clients about this is up to you, and you can see my old answer for some tips on how to approach that.
Generally I'd aim for doing the killing from the server rather than from the client, as you generally shouldn't trust the client with that kind of information. Doing it on the server also means the clients do not have to be exposed to the number, and thus cannot cheat their way to the right door.

---

**Old Answer:**

I am not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if I understand correct you're asking for a way to share a generated number between the server and the client at the start of each session?

This can be done multiple ways. Here are two:
Generate the number in whatever server script you prefer.

1. Expose the number in an IntValue (or NumberValue if decimals are required) somewhere accessible by both server and client such as ReplicatedStorage. All LocalScripts will be able to read this value at any time, and you can hook up the .Changed-event to track changes.
2. Alternatively you can transfer this number over a Remote*-object and just let the LocalScripts request it whenever they need it.

If you're asking whether it is possible to transfer the number between different places (and/or servers of the same place), then yes - that's also possible, but slightly more complex. You can use the newly added MessagingService for this, or store the value in a Datastore. If you don't care much about the security, you can also send the number in the TeleportData of the player's teleport when you send them to the new place.

If I have misunderstood your request, please comment and I'll provide you a better answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment.  Imagine You have 3 entrance to same place but only one is Safe, Two others will kill if you touch them. So once you played it you will know which Entrance is safe.What I want is to have Safe door being random 1st 2nd or 3rd and not same every time new game start. My idea was to get random number picked by server and then based on that decide which door are safe and which will kill. Is there simpler way to get random chosen door to be safe? Sry it makes sense in my head I promise.

Comment: I have updated my original answer @Kromagg. To my understanding the generation of the number was the issue, but please enlighten me if I got your question wrong again. I'll gladly fill in the blanks.